# How to use big font size properly in a low height TextInput in react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

sorry for the silly question. but I'm new to react-native and don't know how to solve my problem.

The problem is **How to make the TextInput's text look normal?**

[image]

This is My Code:

```
return (
    <Fragment>
      <SafeAreaView style={myStyles.fullCenter}>
        <Text style={myStyles.startPageText}>
          Please enter your mobile number
        </Text>
        <TextInput keyboardType="numeric" style={myStyles.enterMobileNumber} />
      </SafeAreaView>
    </Fragment>
  );
};


//STYLE : 
enterMobileNumber: {
    fontFamily: defaultFontFamily,
    fontSize: mobileNumberFontSize,
    borderColor: '#00a7ff',
    borderWidth: 4,
    borderRadius: 60,
    width: 410,
    height: 80,
    paddingHorizontal: 30,
    textAlign: 'center',
    textAlignVertical: 'center',
    lineHeight: mobileNumberFontSize,
  }
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Try creating a container to put your text input. Remove the padding horizontal and put that in the container instead of in the textinput style.

Comment: Sorry, didn't worked, its so strange for me how such a simple thing can't be done easily...

Answer (score 0):

```
    return (
    <Fragment>
      <SafeAreaView style={myStyles.fullCenter}>
        <Text style={myStyles.startPageText}>
          Please enter your mobile number
        </Text>
        <View style={myStyles.textContainer}>
            <TextInput keyboardType="numeric" style={myStyles.enterMobileNumber} />
       </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </Fragment>
  );
};


//STYLE : 
textContainer:{
   paddingHorizontal: 30,
}
enterMobileNumber: {
    fontFamily: defaultFontFamily,
    fontSize: mobileNumberFontSize,
    borderColor: '#00a7ff',
    borderWidth: 4,
    borderRadius: 60,
    width: 410,
    height: 80,
    textAlign: 'center',
    textAlignVertical: 'center',
    lineHeight: mobileNumberFontSize,
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this: This will resolve the issue.

```
return (
        <Fragment>
          <SafeAreaView style={myStyles.fullCenter}>
            <Text style={myStyles.startPageText}>
              Please enter your mobile number
            </Text>
            <TextInput keyboardType="numeric" style={myStyles.enterMobileNumber} />
          </SafeAreaView>
        </Fragment>
      );
    };


    //STYLE : 
    enterMobileNumber: {
        fontFamily: defaultFontFamily,
        fontSize: mobileNumberFontSize,
        borderColor: '#00a7ff',
        borderWidth: 4,
        borderRadius: 60,
        width: 410,
        height: 80,
jsutifyContent : 'center',
alignContent : 'center',
        textAlign: 'center',
        textAlignVertical: 'center',
        //lineHeight: mobileNumberFontSize, line height also might cause the issue.
      }
```